# Android: get Application with a static method

Tags: android

I'm using the pattern of extending `Application` class to save my global variables (https://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/1709805). From my Android Components (`Activity`, `Fragment`, `Service`, ecc) i access them using (`(MyApp) getApplicaction()`), but in my project i have a lot of helper classes where i can't (obviously) use that method. To solve this problem i have decalred a static method which returns the Application. This is the code:

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

  private static MyApp app;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(){
      super.onCreate();
      app = this;
  }

  public static MyApp getApp() {
      return app;
  }
}
```

is it a good pattern? Any suggestion to achieve my purpose in a better way? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Its a Bad practice.

Just use, `MyApp app =  (MyApp)getApplicationContext();` in entire application.

Make sure you have declared **MyApp** in `<application>` tag of **AndroidManifest.xml** file

What you have to do is, When you want to access `MyApp app` object in other Non Android Component class, then pass `MyApp app` as an `argument of Constructor or Method` to non Android Component classes (Helper, Handler or Other Java class) from Android Component Class  (Activity, Fragment, Service, etc).

Comment: ok.. i have evaluated this possibility. it's a solution which works for sure.. but i'm very lazy so I would prefer not pass a reference of MyApp to each class or method ;). Why my approach is so wrong?